# Taking Data From Multiple Table using TestNG Data Provider

Tags: java, selenium-rc, testng

I am Using Selenium RC with TestNG to do some kind of keyword driven testing.For the same purpose i want to read some data from an excel sheet and use it.Here I have used Data Provider annotation of TestNG.but My problem is that i want to read data from multiple tables and use them in a single test method using only one data provider.But I am Getting Problem in it.Can somebody Help me in Doing so.

Thanks

Here Is my Code:

```
@DataProvider(name = "DP1")

public Object[][] createData1() throws Exception {

  return new Object[][] {

    {getTableData.getTableArray(" Xls File Path", "Sheet name", "Table1")},

    {getTableData.getTableArray(" Xls File Path", "Sheet name", "Table2")}

  };

}
```

This Is My Test Method:

```
@Test (dataProvider = ("DP1"))

public void testallpivot(String Command, String Target, String Value) throws Exception {

  //Test Code here


}
```

But This Code is Showing Array Index Out of Bound Exception..
Somebody Please Help me.....

Well this is how getTableArray looks..

```
public static Object[][] getTableArray(String xlFilePath, String sheetName, String     tableName) throws Exception{
    Object[][] tabArray;

        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlFilePath));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName); 
        int startRow,startCol, endRow, endCol,ci,cj;
        Cell tableStart=sheet.findCell(tableName);
        //System.out.println(tableName);
        startRow=tableStart.getRow();
        startCol=tableStart.getColumn();

        Cell tableEnd= sheet.findCell(tableName, startCol+1,startRow+1, 100, 64000,  false);                

        endRow=tableEnd.getRow();
        endCol=tableEnd.getColumn();
        System.out.println("startRow="+startRow+", endRow="+endRow+", " +
                "startCol="+startCol+", endCol="+endCol);
        tabArray=new String[endRow-startRow-1][endCol-startCol-1];
        ci=0;

        for (int i=startRow+1;i<endRow;i++,ci++){
            cj=0;
            for (int j=startCol+1;j<endCol;j++,cj++){
                tabArray[ci][cj]=sheet.getCell(j,i).getContents();
            }
        }


    return(tabArray);
}
```

And this is the Stack Trace.....

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.injectParameters(Invoker.java:1144)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1020)
atorg.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:137)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:121)
at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:953)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:633)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:316)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:195)
at org.testng.TestNG.createAndRunSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:903)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:872)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:780)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:75)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:127)
```

Comment: Array Index Out Of Bound occurs whenever the array points to an array which does not exist... May be, we have to check on the increments in the for loop to resolve this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't help you much if you don't include the stack trace and also what getTableArray() returns (it should be Object[]).

Comment: Like I said, getTableArray needs to return an Object[] since you are returning an array of getTableArray() in your data provider, thereby creating a triple array (Object[][][]).

Comment: Ok dats fine..but here my question is why its working fine when i take data from a single table like dis...

@DataProvider(name = "DP1")
 
public Object[][] createData() throws Exception {

  Object[][] retObjArr = getTableData
    .getTableArray(
Xls File Path","SheetName", "Table1");
      

  return (retObjArr);

 }

Comment: Because in this case, you are not wrapping the value returned by getTableArray() in an array.

Comment: Either have your data provider return exactly one invocation of getTableArray() (since it returns an Object[][], which is what a data provider should return), or modify getTableArray() to return an Object[] and return an array of these in your data provider.

Answer (score 0):

you can return only one array by copying the second in to first. Try something like:

```
List<Object[]>  retVal = Arrays.asList
    (getTableData.getTableArray(" Xls File Path", "Sheet name", "Table1"));
retVal.addAll(
    Arrays.asList(getTableData.getTableArray(" Xls File Path", "Sheet name", "Table2")));
return retVal.toArray();
```

Comment: Hey thanks fr ur suggestion but it dint worked fr me..Its also showing the same problem..:(

Answer (score -1):

If you open the Excel sheet while executing code then this error is found. Please make sure you save and close excel doc before executing test cases.